# Make a "List of lists" in addition to "List of figures", and "List of tables"

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to include a "List of lists" to appear after "List of figures" and "List of tables". Therefore I cannot simply change the heading of either of those, I need to create a new "List of lists". How can this be done? It would not be an issue for me to do this manually in each list.

The floating environment is made like this

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=List]{mylist}
```

And then create lists like this

```
\begin{mylist}
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Items go here, as usual
    \end{itemize}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{list:some-list}
\end{mylist}
```

I did it this way in order to have a caption and label, in addition to making it a floating environment, like figures.

Comment: `\listoflists` should already work (it is defined by `newfloat` when you create a new float type).

Comment: Maybe `\listofmylists`, I'm not sure how the `name` argument interacts with this.

Comment: Thank you! The solution is \listofmylists, otherwise I got an error (Undefined control sequence)

Comment: In the manual of newfloat you can find some more options, for example setting the title of the list.

Comment: Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

\listofmylists was automatically defined when I made the floating environment, as mentioned by @Marijn in the comments.

More info can be found in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newfloat/newfloat.pdf)

Comment: It's better to link to the generic url (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newfloat/newfloat.pdf), if the University of Bergen stops hosting their CTAN mirror then your link will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tocloft` package, which can provide non-floating, but captioned and referenceable lists.

```
% newlistprob.tex  SE 639634

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% enable a List of Lists
\newcommand{\listoflistname}{List of Lists}
\newlistof[section]{lists}{lst}{\listoflistname}

% Specify the code for a list
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{lists}
  \par\noindent\textbf{List \thelists. #1}
  \addcontentsline{lst}{lists}{\protect\numberline{\thelists}#1}\par}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoflists

\section{Begin}

\mylist{First list}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\label{Flist}

List \ref{Flist} is the first list.

\mylist{Second list}
\begin{itemize}
\item C
\item D
\end{itemize}
\label{Slist}

List \ref{Slist} is another list.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the `tocloft` package manual for more information.